# Как отобразить xps документ с помощью binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как сделать с помощью binding, чтобы указанный xps файл во viewmodel отображался в окне? C помощью DocumentViewer это сделать не получается. Вот мой код,

```
class DocViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private DocumentViewer documentViewer1 = new DocumentViewer();
    public DocViewModel()
    {
        XpsDocument document = new XpsDocument(@"D:\help_pages\page1.xps", FileAccess.Read);
        documentViewer1.Document = document.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

    }

    public DocumentViewer DocumentViewer1
    {
        get
        { return documentViewer1; }
        set
        {
            documentViewer1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DocumentViewer1");
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
<Grid>
    <DocumentViewer Name="DocumentViewer1" Document="{Binding Path=DocumentViewer1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: DataContext для DocumentViewer задан?

Comment: DataContext для DocumentViewer задан

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DocumentViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="DocumentViewer1" Document="{Binding Doc, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Open" Margin="1" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private XpsDocument _xpsDocument;
    private IDocumentPaginatorSource _doc;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DocumentViewer1.DataContext = this;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public IDocumentPaginatorSource Doc
    {
        get
        {
            return _doc;
        }
        set
        {
            _doc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Doc");
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _xpsDocument = new XpsDocument("C:/1234567.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        Doc = _xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }
}
```